# Mysqldump from remote server return only System Variables

Tags: mysql

I´m trying to do a mysqldump from remote server.
In command line in Windows i have this command:
**@call mysqldump --host=remotehost --user=user --password=password database > "Dump.sql"**

But my created SQL file contains only system variables but no data:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.20, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: xxxxxxxxxx    Database: xxxxxxxx
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

I´ve tried to add --port=3306, change host to --host=IPremotehost but nothing helps.

**EDIT: Problem solved. I haven´t rights to do dump with that user. Missing "LOCK TABLES"**

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the database in question actually has any tables?  You might have a typo in the database name.

My first check would be to log into the database remotely on the the same computer you're running mysqldump from and use the same ip and credentials and then do a 'show tables' to see if there are any tables in the database.